# Passing shortcode attributes to WordPress Remote Post URL

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I'm trying to pass shortcode attribute values directly into my url for a WordPress Remote Post request. Below is my code example below. I am using the following shortcode in my wordpress page

[example-data start="1" count="10"]

but i cannot get the start or the count data to work in the URL. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function display_example_data( $atts ) {

$value = shortcode_atts( array(
    'start' => 1,
    'count' => 10,
), $atts );

$url ="https://example.com/api/reviews?token=".$api_text_key."&start=".$value['start']."&count=".$value['count']."";

    $response = wp_remote_post( $url, array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'timeout' => 45,
        'redirection' => 5,
        'httpversion' => '1.0',
        'blocking' => true,
        'headers' => array(),
        'cookies' => array()
        )
    );

<?php }

add_shortcode( 'example-data', 'display_example_data' );
```